# Java: вчерашняя дата

Tags: android, java

Как узнать на Джаве вчерашнюю дату?

Например, сегодня 16.12.2012.
А нужно высчитать 15.12.2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println("Yesterday's date = "+ cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен стандартный класс [java.util.Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) который умеет делать всякие преобразования даты/времени. Для Вашего случая будет достаточно метода add. Но  помните, что преобразования дат, не всегда такая тривиальная задача и иногда может давать очень странные результаты. Например, иногда добавляя час к текущему времени, можно получить тоже время (а потом оказывается что это была осень и переводили часы час назад).

Comment: Для сложных задач лучше пользоваться [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) умеет делать правильно.